# Setting Language for Addthis Share Buttons

Tags: locale, addthis, share-button

When I click one of the share buttons, the popups and new pages are in English.

Is there a way I can set them to be a different language?

I have set the `ui_language` in `addthis_conf` but seeing as I am using custom images, I don't think that really matters.

```
var addthis_conf = {
    ui_language: "fr"
};
```

I know, for instance, that the native Twitter button uses the `data-lang` attribute to set the language of the popup content (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button).

Is there something like that I can use for `Addthis` buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The ui_lang parameter will adjust the language for all elements of the AddThis UI and doesn't have an effect on your images.

Comment: Does the "Addthis UI" include the dialog boxes that show up when you click on a button?

For instance, if I set the ui_language to be "fr," will the Twitter dialog box be in French?

If that's the case, it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: It includes everything that we have control over. The Twitter button opens a page on Twitter.com, which we don't have any control over.