# Define AddThis share buttons to one language

Tags: javascript, addthis

I'm using the AddThis share buttons on my site but I have a problem which is the buttons language changed depending on user browser language.

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-552ac4af2fde1432" async="async"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div>
```

I used this code to set one language but it didn't worked

```
var addthis_config = {
      ui_language: "fr" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the button too. Try it:

```
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php"
    class="addthis_button"><img
    src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-fr.gif"
    width="125" height="16" border="0" alt="Share" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately my buttons look like this http://i.imgur.com/gqGD1LV.png not like the image in the code you gave me

Comment: I need the icons to look like in the image I showed you but in French not like this http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-fr.gif

Comment: So, look it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123091/setting-language-for-addthis-share-buttons